# My VDHL code runs incorrectly - square root in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, square-root

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity RaccinCarreSequentielle is

generic(    
    N: natural:= 16
    );
port(
    X: unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0);
    reset : in std_logic; --clear signal
    clk : in std_logic;
    state_done :  in std_logic; --start
    result_done : out std_logic;
    result :      out unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture state_machine_raccincarre_arc of RaccinCarreSequentielle is
    type state is (s0_wait,s1_init,s2_calcul,s3_fini);
    signal pre_state,next_state: state;
begin
    state_register:process(reset,clk)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            pre_state <= s0_wait;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            pre_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process state_register;

state_machine: process(pre_state,state_done)
    variable rx,rz,rv : unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0);
    variable ri: unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
begin
    case pre_state is
        when s0_wait =>
            if state_done = '1' then
                next_state <= s1_init;
            else 
                next_state <= s0_wait;
            end if;
        when s1_init => 
            next_state <= s2_calcul;
            rx := x;
            rz := (others => '0');
            rv := (2*N-2 => '1', others => '0');
            ri := to_unsigned(N-1,N);
        when s2_calcul =>
            if ri > 0 then
                    ri := ri - 1;
                    rz := rz + rv;
                    if rx > rz then
                         rx := rx - rz;
                         rz := rz + rv;
                    else 
                         rz := rz - rv;
                    end if;
                    rz := '0' & rz(2*N-1 downto 1);
                    rv := "00" & rv(2*N-1 downto 2);
                    next_state <= s2_calcul;
                 else
                    next_state <= s3_fini;
            end if;
        when s3_fini =>
            result <= rz;           
            if state_done = '0' then
                next_state <= s0_wait;
            else 
                next_state <= s3_fini;
            end if;
        when others =>
            null;
    end case;
end process state_machine;
                
result_proc: process(pre_state)
begin
    if pre_state = s3_fini then
        result_done <= '1';
    else 
        result_done <= '0';
    end if;
end process result_proc;
end architecture;
```

When i use the for loop inside state2, my code will run correctly and my result is good. For example when i want to find the square root of 255, i will have 15. But when I dont want to use For loop in state2_calcul as you see. So i did a if statement to reduce the variable RI each time i go to state2 like below. I did a simulation but the state always stops at state2, it can not go through like my link.

[image: https://ibb.co/6HVWNHC]

```
when s2_calcul =>
    if ri > 0 then
            ri := ri - 1;
            rz := rz + rv;
            if rx > rz then
                 rx := rx - rz;
                 rz := rz + rv;
            else 
                 rz := rz - rv;
            end if;
            rz := '0' & rz(2*N-1 downto 1);
            rv := "00" & rv(2*N-1 downto 2);
            next_state <= s2_calcul;
         else
            next_state <= s3_fini;
    end if;
```

I think that problem is the nested IF, but when i change that, nothing change. Could someone helps me explain that problem and how can i solve it. thanks

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The problem can't be replicated without a testbench. Reading a 32 bit binary value for the X input is painful.  In the variable assignment `rv := (2*N-2 => '1', others => '0');` the expression `2*N-2` is not locally static (contains generic constant N, it's globally static) and the others choice is not allowed in the right hand expression, an aggregate. See IEEE Std 1076-1993 7.3.2.2 Array aggregates, para 2 or -2008 9.3.3.3 para 6. Whose simulator and version? What revision of the VHDL standard? Error messages?

Comment: From paragraph 2/6: "A named association of an array aggregate is allowed to have a choice that is not locally static, or likewise a choice that is a null range, only if the aggregate includes a single element association and this element association has a single choice."

Comment: Once you have the design model straightened out for portability without any 'relaxed-rules' nonsense and been supplied a testbench your readers would find that `s2_calcul` is only traversed once because there are no signals in the state_machine process's sensitivity list that have been updated.  The process suspends and never resumes. This can be demonstrated with report statements.

Comment: Your `state_machine` process is supposed to be a combinatorial process, not a synchronous process with registers, right? So, what do you think will happen with the `ri`, `rx` and `rz` variables that you sometimes read before assigning them? What hardware do you think will be synthesized to "_remember_" their value from one process execution to the next? Latches. Something you probably don't want in your design. It is time to stop coding and to start thinking pure hardware. Can you draw a block diagram of the hardware you want? If not, VHDL coding is premature.

Comment: And your `state_machine` combinatorial process suffers two more problems: 1) `x` shall be in the sensitivity list. 2) You assign `next_state` in all branches of the control flow but not `result`. What do you think the synthesizer will do to "_remember_" its last assigned value when the process resumes and does not assign a new value? Latches again. Think hardware: do you want to store this `result` somewhere to keep it stable? Then it must be in a register and you cannot model this register in a combinatorial process like `state_machine`.

Comment: Finally, you should remove the `when others` choice in the `case` statement of your `state_machine` combinatorial process. As all possible choices have been listed it is useless. But if you decide to add a fifth value to the `state` type and you forget to handle it properly in the case statement, this `when others` choice will hide it. You will have no warning or error. And guess what the synthesizer will use to "_remember_" the value of `next_state` (and `result`) when falling in this extra state? Latches again... While without it you will get a clear error message.

Comment: When i used if-stetament instead of for loop, i want it works in sequence, i mean it will calculate code inside, reduce it and do it again till ri = 0. I don't want it will calculate just one time in s2_calcul. But i haven't found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot memorize anything in a combinatorial part of your design. So you need registers for `ri`, `rx`, `rv` and `rz`. These registers are somehow part of your global state which is indeed a combination of them, and of the `pre_state` register.

Let's continue with the style you already use: one synchronous process for the registers, another for the combinatorial part, and a `next_xxx` signal for the input of each `xxx` register.

```vhdl
architecture state_machine_raccincarre_arc of RaccinCarreSequentielle is
    type state is (s0_wait, s1_init, s2_calcul, s3_fini);
    signal pre_state, next_state: state;
    signal rx, rz, rv, next_rx, next_rz, next_rv: unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0);
    signal ri, next_ri: unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
begin
    state_register:process(reset,clk)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            pre_state <= s0_wait;
            rx <= (others => '0');
            rz <= (others => '0');
            ri <= (others => '0');
            rv <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            pre_state <= next_state;
            rx <= next_rx;
            rz <= next_rz;
            ri <= next_ri;
            rv <= next_rv;
        end if;
    end process state_register;

    state_machine: process(pre_state, state_done, x, rx, rz, rv, ri)
        variable tmpz : unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0);
    begin
        next_state <= pre_state;
        next_rx    <= rx;
        next_rz    <= rz;
        next_rv    <= rv;
        next_ri    <= ri;
        tmpz       := (others => '0');
        case pre_state is
            when s0_wait =>
                if state_done = '1' then
                    next_state <= s1_init;
                end if;
            when s1_init =>
                next_state <= s2_calcul;
                next_rx <= x;
                next_rz <= (others => '0');
                next_rv <= (others => '0');
                next_rv(2*N-2) <= '1';
                next_ri <= to_unsigned(N-1,N);
            when s2_calcul =>
                if ri > 0 then
                    next_ri <= ri - 1;
                    tmpz := rz + rv;
                    if rx > tmpz then
                        next_rx <= rx - tmpz;
                        tmpz := tmpz + rv;
                    else
                        tmpz := tmpz - rv;
                    end if;
                    next_rz <= '0' & tmpz(2*N-1 downto 1);
                    next_rv <= "00" & rv(2*N-1 downto 2);
                else
                    next_state <= s3_fini;
                end if;
            when s3_fini =>
                if state_done = '0' then
                    next_state <= s0_wait;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process state_machine;

    result <= rz;
    result_done <= '1' when pre_state = s3_fini else '0';
end architecture;
```

See? The sensitivity list of the combinatorial process contains **all** signals that the process reads, the signals it assigns are always assigned (thanks to the default assignments at the very beginning), and the only variable is always assigned before it is used (thanks also to the default assignment at the very beginning).

Note that, thanks to the default assignments at the very beginning, there is no risk to get latches at synthesis. By default these:

```vhdl
next_xxx <= xxx;
```

assignments say that by default the `xxx` register shall not change. An interesting side effect is that you do not need any more some of your `else` statements. You can replace:

```vhdl
        when s0_wait =>
            if state_done = '1' then
                next_state <= s1_init;
            else 
                next_state <= s0_wait;
            end if;
```

by:

```vhdl
        when s0_wait =>
            if state_done = '1' then
                next_state <= s1_init;
            end if;
```

because the `else` clause is already what happens by default.

Of course, it could be that it does not work exactly as you would like because the structure is totally different. But at least this should be a good starting point for your debugging. Just remember the main principles of combinatorial processes for synthesis:

1. the sensitivity list **must** contain **all** signals that the process reads (the `all` keyword of the VHDL 2008 standard is helpful, if your tools support it),
2. the signals it assigns (its outputs) **must** be assigned **each time** the process resumes (default assignments at the very beginning can be handy for beginners),
3. the variables **must** always be assigned **before** they are used (default assignments at the very beginning can be handy for beginners).

Be careful, these 3 golden rules are not that easy to check, especially in complicated nested `if` and `case` statements. This is why I always suggest to beginners to use the trick of default assignments at the very beginning. Rules #2 and #3 become trivial. For rule #1, if your tools support the `all` keyword of the VHDL 2008 standard, use it for all combinatorial processes (**not for synchronous processes**):

```vhdl
state_machine: process(all)
```

Comment: @user16145658 "_The 'golden rules' appear to rely on testimonial in lieu of references or the standard_" Did you already synthesize a design that violates these rules? And yes, I always try to answer questions that are reasonably understandable. In my humble opinion SO is also here to help people who need help. I understand that you have a different point of view and tend to demand modifications until the question is perfect or not far from that. Let's agree that we disagree on this. Feel free to downvote if you think my answer deserves it, no offence, I'm not chasing reputation.

Comment: Writing a testbench to recreated the OP's waveform (as much as possible, the time scale is unknown) shows us [the answer's architecture provides a square root that is off by a factor of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xxR.jpg) according to my MacOS scientific calculator app.

Comment: Reason why I wrote "_Of course, it could be that it does not work exactly as you would like because the structure is totally different. But at least this should be a good starting point for your debugging_". I did not check the algorithm nor the way it was initially implemented because this was not the question. The question was about the state machine being stuck in a state. My answer was how to properly design such a machine and the pitfalls to avoid. Hopefully, with the provided knowledge, the OP will quickly find why an iteration is missing or why there is one more than needed.